# jQuery: Adding background image to div

Tags: jquery, path, background-image

Im trying to add the background-image source to a div using jquery.

The image path is stored in a variable that gets the value from an input field. So if the user types in the input field `img/my-image.jpg`, then I add the background-image style to the div like this

```
var imgSource = $("input").val();

$("div").css("background-image","url("+ imgSource +")");
```

The problem is that instead of the image source coming out exactly as the user typed, It comes out like this `http://localhost/website/img/my-image.jpg`

So if the user types the image path `img/mountain.jpg`, instead of the source being added exactly like that, its instead added like this.

```
http://localhost/website/img/mountain.jpg
```

How can i have the background image path that the user entered be exactly what its added and not start from localhost?

Comment: The browser ultimately needs a full path to display the image. I'm guessing the localhost is some sort of default. Can you prepend the current host address before the user input in your jQuery code?

Comment: not sure if i get u right ... url(" + window.location.hostname + "/" imgSource + ... tried this?

Comment: try this might help

var imgSource ="url("+ $("input").val() +")";
$("div").css("background-image",  imgSource );

Comment: These didn't work. This is how I have it. .css("background-image","url("+ window.location.hostname + "/" + bgImageSRC +")");

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the correct URI to image. Relative path's to images is only recommend when you have sure where the image is located and where you calling the image.

Also, you can get the base url, like this in PHP:

```
<?php echo dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>
```

At the most frameworks(and languages), this kind of function is provided.

In javascript, you can do with following code:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
```

And then concatened with the imgSource:

```
var imgSource = $("input").val();
var base_url = window.location.origin;

$("div").css("background-image","url("+ base_url .'/'.imgSource +")");
```

Comment: I still get http:localhost before the actual image path.

Comment: This also happens with paths created for anchor tags.

Comment: You can try to use a virtual host too. I thinks it's better if you can't get the base url from backend.

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution to this issue.